# Gettimg Error i.e (NullPointException) 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference can anyone help solving error

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception

This is my logcat

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

```
    at com.chetan.mobchat.Activities.MainActivity$4.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:180)

    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)

    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)

    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8218)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

This is Code

database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

```
        @Override

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            users.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);

                if(!user.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()))

                    users.add(user);

            }

            binding.recyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();

            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }


        @Override

        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {


        }

    });
```

Can Anyone help me in solving this error

Comment: Don't just repost the same question. If you don't think the linked post in your original question answers the question, edit your question to explain why not.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you attempted to call the .equals function from an null reference object. The only use of .equals that I could find in your code is on this line:

```
if(!user.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()))
```

The user.**getUid().equals** is the culprit here. user.getUid() must be returning a null value. Try to find some documentation on this 'user' object, and you may have more luck.